# Swift Warning: A lonng-running operation is being executed on the main thread

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

Hello please help me solving this problm!

i'm getting this output:

First output is: (lldb) only!

Until I press Continue program execution Three times then i got this:

> Warning: A lonng-running operation is being executed on the main thread.
>
> Break on WarnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
>
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>
> (lldb)

I think the problem with this code:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username != '"+userName+"'")

var query = PFQuery(className: "_User", predicate: predicate)

var objects = query.findObjects()


for object in objects {

self.resualtprofilename.append(object["profileName"] as String)

self.rtable.reloadData()

}
```

Please help me to solve this! And i hate (lldb) it always bothering me I don't know what's mean.

> i'm using xcode 6.0 with Latest Parse SKD IOS

Comment: He long running task warning is because you are using `findObjects` rather than `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. The nil message is because something you said wasn't nil is.

Comment: Hello Paul, Thank you for your reply! but can you just teach me how to fix it by writing codes? how can i use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock and that will solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

All that you need replace

> findObjects

with

> findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

and dont forget get the code from parse